# preg_replace for a specific URL containing parameters

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace the session ID # of a list of URLS

Ex: http://www.yes.com/index.php?session=e4bce57bc39f67bebde0284f4c2ed9ba&id=1234

I'm trying to get rid of the `session=e4bce57bc39f67bebde0284f4c2ed9ba` bit and just keep the `http://www.yes.com/index.php?id=1234` bit.

I'm attempting to use:

```
preg_replace('&\bhttp://www\.yes\.com/(?:index\.php(?:\?id(?:=[]\d!"#$%\'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\\\_`a-z{|}~^-]*+)?&i', $subject, $regs))
```

But it isn't work. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `preg_match` does not replace. I think you mean `preg_replace`.

Comment: I'd use `parse_url()` and `parse_str()` myself.  Why reinvent URL parsing when PHP already has url parsing facilities?

Comment: oh right, I always forget about that function. and yeah, i meant replace ;\

Comment: Eh, but if you use `parse_url()` you still end up having to `parse_str()` just seems like a bit of wasted code if the preg can just spit it out

Comment: @tr3online: considering your proposed regex pattern, your idea of "wasted code" is definitely peculiar. Builtin functions are the way to go IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to strip out the `&session=...` part then preg_replace might be the best option. It also makes sense to look just for that part then and not to assert the URL structure:

```
$url = preg_replace("/([?&])session=\w+(&|$)/", "$1", $url);
```

This pattern looks that it's either enclosed by two `&`, and/or begins with an `?` and/or is the last thing in the string. `\w+` is sufficient to match the session id string.

Comment: What about the triplet encodings that can appear in the query string?

Comment: Doesn't seem likely enough in OPs case to warrant a more elaborate code snippet.

Comment: Obviously, but maybe the regex you suggest does not look complicated enough to fullfill the OPs desires.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I only need the two args. Nothing else is generated, so the regex doesn't need to be any more complicated than it is. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more verbose than a regex, but you can do this using PHP's own functions for url handling, `parse_url`, `parse_str`, `http_build_url` and `http_build_query`.

```
// Parse the url to constituent parts
$url_parts = parse_url($_REQUEST);

// Parse query string to $params array
parse_str($url_parts['query'], $params);

// Get rid of the session param
unset($params['session']);

// Rebuild query part of the url without the session val
$url_parts['query'] = http_build_query($params);

// Rebuild the url using http_build_url
$cleaned_url = http_build_url(
    "http://www.example.com"
    , $url_parts
);
```

Comment: Are you sure about `implode("&", $params);`?

Comment: Hm. That would be slightly better than the code I came up with the exception that http_build_url() is undefined. I'm just running a basic XAMPP installation. I assume it's not turned on. I was wondering the same about the implode() but I cant check it.

Comment: @hakre with implode("&", $params) the intention is to allow for more than one non-removed query param to remain, being joined by "&" if more than one remains after removal of session.

Comment: But you need to deal with keys and values. I think there is a counter-part to `parse_str` you're actually looking for. Maybe http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php ?